# Could someone help with a renaissance musical translation?

Tags: translation-check, music

I am trying to translate a Latin title, reproduced below:

> Missæ tres Petro Certon pueris simphoniacis sancti sacelli Parisiensis auctore, nunc primúm in lucem ædit[a]e, cum quatuor vocibus, ad imitationem modulorum. Lutetiae

Here is my attempted translation of which I'm unsure:

> Three masses by Pierre Certon,for the boys choir of the holy shrine of Paris, newly published, in four voices, imitating (something)

A Google books bibliographical entry is [available here](https://books.google.com/books/about/Missae_tres_Petro_Certon_pueris_simphoni.html?id=Dkt3nQEACAAJ).  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the book about? Any description might help parse the title.

Comment: Three masses by Pierre Certon,for the boys choir  of the holy shrine of Paris, newly published, in four voices, imitating (something)

Comment: The chap is Pierre Certon

Comment: @Ceruusdemens I'm confused: you just answered your own question.

Comment: I'm sorry,I'm pretty much a newcomer to Latin and writing it down sometimes helps to answer my own question. Do you think my understanding of the phrase is correct?

Comment: @Ceruusdemens Yes: it's actually a much more serviceable translation than mine, which was intended to show the literal meaning.

Comment: @Ceruusdemens I edited your own translation into the question. Feel free to re-edit. Showing your own attempt is generally a very good idea.

Comment: @Ceruusdemens It seems that you have not gone through [our site tour (link)](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) yet. I warmly recommend doing so!

Answer (score 6):

The translation is fairly straightforward. Here is a literal rendering:

> Three Masses, with Pierre Certon as author, for the choristers of the Sainte-Chapelle of Paris, now published for the first time, in four voices, in imitation of the melodies X.

[Lutetia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutetia) (Locative: *Lutetiae*) is simply the old Roman name for Paris, and indicates the city where it was published.

Some notes:

- A *missa* in this context is a setting of the ordinary of the Mass: the Kyrie, Gloria, Credo (sometimes), Sanctus, Benedictus, and Agnus Dei.
- A [*sacellum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsacellum) (diminutive of *sacrum*) is a "little sanctuary." In this context, and based on the biography of [Pierre Certon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Certon), this certainly refers to the Sainte-Chapelle.
- [*symphoniacus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsymphoniacus) ("y" changed to "i", as common in later Latin) is an adjective for a concert. Combined with *puer*, it refers to a boys choir.
- I was stuck with "ad imitationem modulorum" until I realized that something is surely being left out. As you can see in [this bibliography for Pierre Certon](https://books.google.com/books?id=0eMxAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383), "modulorum" (or "moduli," if only one) should be followed the names of the melodies that are being imitated. It was quite common in Renaissance music to use a folk song as a point of departure for the mass's themes.

Comment: I think you've got it exactly right. Such masses are commonly known as 'parody masses' -- or, as the term that's used here suggests, 'imitation masses'.

Comment: @cnread Interesting: they were still sung at actual ceremonies though, right? I once sang a Lassus mass of this kind.